# Show bg image with progress-bar on splash screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, splash-screen, android-theme

I am trying to show a BG Image and Progress-bar on splash screen.

Code for splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="@drawable/spalsh">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@layout/progressbartemplate"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then on Style I have

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background" >@layout/splash</item>
    </style>
```

Then I applied this style to Activity in manifiestfile

```
<activity
            android:name="com.test.SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But when the app starts I can not see the image and progress-bar while same i can see on the design view.
Same code will work if i use Layer-List and remove the progressbar.

Can someone pls suggest me how can i show the bg image with progress-bar at bottom?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you have a dedicated activity for splash then put the progress in it's layout.xml file and show it for a specific time then finish the activity

Comment: also check [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/revisited-a-guide-on-splash-screen-in-android-in-2020-bbcd4bb1ce42) for different ways in showing splash

Comment: @MohammedAlaa If i use activity's layout to show the splash screen then user can see a blank screen for a while when he taps on the app first time to start it.

Comment: @Paven Tiwari yes , you are right , but what you are doing is that you need to make xml layout file as a background right? I don't know if this is doable or not ,as how can you inflate this layout and the activity didn't start yet?

Comment: @MohammedAlaa As i mentioned in the question, "Same code will work if i use Layer-List and remove the progressbar." i am wondering why

Comment: @Paven Tiwari progressbar is an android View which can't be placed in drawable folder , so you can place Bitmaps or Shaps  in layer-list as they aren't Android Views

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem in size of splash image you have to resize it by follow blow steps

1- right click on res

2- right click on drawable

3- click on new

4- Batch Drawable importer

5- click on plus + chose splash

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

try this, I hope this may resolve your issue.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    tools:context="com.example.viral.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="12dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```